# Check if two lists are equal in any order

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

Suppose I have two lists, how can I efficiently check if the two lists are identical up to permutations of the elements?

For example I would like the function to output:

```
AreListsEqual[{a,b,c},{a,c,b}] = True
AreListsEqual[{a,b,c},{a,b,d}] = False
AreListsEqual[{a,b,c},{a,c,b,d}] = False
```

**Update**: In response to a comment by @KellenMyers, it does appear the best way to do this depends on the particular sets that are being compared. I am looking at comparing two sets that

1. About 1%-50% of the tests will return false.
2. Very few repeated items in the list

where most of the results will return false.

Comment: At this point it seems clear that the answer that makes the most sense depends on your data. Could you follow up and let us know: (1) Do you have repeated items in your "list" or is it a "set"/"permutation"? and (2) Do you expect to use this in a setting where most tests return `True` or most return `False`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is it any permutation ? Then I think then this should do

```
areListsEqual[List1_,List2_]:=(Sort[List1]===Sort[List2]);
```

Answer (score 13):

If you have many duplicates (and the number of duplicates matter) then `Tally` can improve performance sufficiently

```
orderlessSameQ[a_List, b_List] := (Length@a == Length@b) && (Sort@Tally@a === Sort@Tally@b);

a = RandomInteger[{0, 1000}, 1000000];
b = RandomSample[a];

areListsEqual[a, b] // AbsoluteTiming (* lalmei *)
orderlessSameQ[a, b] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.577613, True} *)
(* {0.011876, True} *)
```

Comment: Ah, what I was thinking about, `List` complicates that. But I suppose this may work: `Total[Join[h @@@ Tally[a], -h @@@ Tally[b]]] === 0`.

Answer (score 7):

The `Permutations` method will be unnecessarily slow, but if you are talking about *elements* of a *set* (I'm not sure -- your terminology isn't clear), you can speed things up **if you are expecting to see mostly `False` as output** by doing the following:

```
areListsEqual[s1_, s2_] := Module[{i = 1, n = Length[s1]},
 If[Not[n == Length[s2]], Return[False]];
 While[i < n, If[Not[MemberQ[s2, s1[[i]], 1]], Return[False]]; i++;];
 Return[True];
];
```

Note that I'm using levelspec 1 in the `MemberQ` command, so that if you have lists of lists this still makes some sense. If you compare this with the other method, it might not be noticeable:

```
areListsEqual2[List1_, List2_] := (Sort[List1] === Sort[List2]);
Timing[areListsEqual[{a, b, c}, {c, b, a}]]
Timing[areListsEqual2[{a, b, c}, {c, b, a}]]

(* Output:
 {0., True}
 {0., True} *)
```

However, you'll see it on larger lists, whether they are different:

```
s1 = DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[10^10, 10^7]];
s2 = Take[DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[10^10, 2*10^7]], Length[s1]];
Timing[areListsEqual[s1, s2]]
Timing[areListsEqual2[s1, s2]]

(* Output:
 {0.717605, False}
 {3.900025, False} *)
```

and of course, the opposite result if they are actually equal:

```
s1 = DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[10^10, 10^4]];
s2 = {}; iv = Range[Length[s1]];
While[iv != {},
 i = RandomInteger[{1, Length[iv]}];
 s2 = Append[s2, s1[[iv[[i]]]]];
 iv = Drop[iv, {i}];
];
Timing[areListsEqual[s1, s2]]
Timing[areListsEqual2[s1, s2]]

(* Output:
 {1.466409, True}
 {0., True} *)
```

Note that in any event, when the two lists are longer, both methods take much longer (which is why I've restricted that one to size $10^4$ and not $10^7$. Even using a set size of roughly $10^5$.

And of course, when they actually don't agree in length, it's much easier to see:

```
s1 = DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[10^10, 10^7]];
s2 = Take[DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[10^10, 2*10^7]], Length[s1] + 1];
Timing[areListsEqual[s1, s2]]
Timing[areListsEqual2[s1, s2]]

(* Output:
 {0., False}
 {3.884425, False} *)
```

And can you imagine comparing a list of size $10^{10}$ with one of size $10^{10}+1$? You'd have to sort each one just to decide they aren't equal! Of course, who has the RAM for that?

So if you are expecting lots of lists to go through this that are clearly and obviously not the same, with lots of `False` output, you might want to try this method. If you are expecting to generally see lists that are the same or almost exactly the same (or which have repeated elements -- something I could, but have not, accounted for), you can stick to the `Sort` and `===` method. And of course, if your lists are of relatively small size, the question of efficiency is moot anyway.

**Last minute note:** I just saw eldo's answer, and I will note that his method is even slower than the `Sort` and `===` method in the case of `False` output. His time is `4.383628` for that first legitimate comparison and `4.274427` for the second (when the lists are different sizes). It also clocks in at `0.` in the case where my method is slower (i.e. the `True` output).

Comment: A very diligent and interesting analysis, +1

Answer (score 4):

### [OrderlessPatternSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html?q=OrderlessPatternSequence)

```
orderlessMatchQ = MatchQ[#, {OrderlessPatternSequence @@ #2}] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
orderlessMatchQ[{a, b, c}, {a, c, b}]
```

> True

```
orderlessMatchQ[{a, c, b}, {a, b, c}]
```

> True

```
orderlessMatchQ[{a, b, c}, {a, b, d}]
```

> False

```
orderlessMatchQ[{a, b, c}, {a, c, b, d}]
```

> False

Comment: This is slower than  ybeltukov's `orderlessSameQ` and lalmei's `areListsEqual`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `UniqueElements` (new in 13.1)

```
SameElements[a_][b_] := Flatten @ UniqueElements[{a, b}] == {}

SameElements[{a, b, c}] /@ {{a, c, b}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, b, d}}
```

{True, False, False}

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use `Counts` and `ContainsOnly` as follows:

```
SameElements[a_, b_] := ContainsOnly[Counts[Join[a, b]], {2}]

SameElements[{a, b, c}, #] & /@ {{a, c, b}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, b, d}}

(*{True, False, False}*)

SameElements[{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}]

(*False*)

SameElements[{a, b, c}, {a, b, b}]

(*False*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is elegant way. Not fast but pretty

```
func[lst1_List, lst2_List] := Module[{f1, f2, x},
  SetAttributes[f1, Orderless];
  SetAttributes[f2, Orderless];
  f1[x__] := x;
  f2[x__] := x;
  TrueQ[{f1 @@ lst1} == {f2 @@ lst2}]
  ]
```

Comment: Doesn't function with me. Could you produce some output?

Comment: @eldo, fogot `TrueQ` at the last line. And with this funtion work fine

Answer (score 1):

Using the Complement function, we can define AreListsEqual very simply as:

```
    AreListsEqual[list1_, list2_] := 
      Complement[list1, list2] == Complement[list2, list1];
```

Duplicates in each list are ignored. Hence, for example,

```
    AreListsEqual[{a,a,b}, {a,b}] == True
```

Unfortunately, if the lists are large, it's quite slow. Using @Kellen-Myers' lists,

```
    s1 = DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[10^10, 10^7]];
    s2 = Take[DeleteDuplicates[RandomInteger[10^10, 2*10^7]], Length[s1] + 1];
    Timing[AreListsEqual[s1, s2]]
     (* Output: 
         {10.0881, False}
      *)
```